# Простое CRUD приложение на React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, crud

Есть ли хорошие туториалы где объясняется как реализовать CRUD приложение на React'e?
Желательно с использование json-сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таких курсов очень много в интернете. Лучше начать с изучения [официальной документации](https://reactjs.org/).
Если нет желания углубляться в детали, а хочется перейти сразу к делу, могу посоветовать этот курс https://coursehunters.net/course/react-node-fullstack-socialnaya-set-s-nulya-do-razvertyvaniya.

Comment: уже качая спасибо )